# Check from View if Record Exists in Rails has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_many through:` relationship in my app where `people` have many `occasions` through `gifts` and visa versa.

It's set up properly in the models:

`person.rb` is like this:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :gifts
has_many :occasions, through: :gifts
```

`occasion.rb` is like this:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :gifts
has_many :people, through: :gifts
```

`gift.rb` is like this:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :occasion
```

In the view I'm trying to make a table with `people` on the y axis, `occasions` on the x axis, and `gifts` in the appropriate cells.  I have this in my `gifts#index` view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <th>Recipient</th>
        <% @occasions.each do |occasion| %>
            <th><%= occasion.name %></th>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#edit-recipient-popup" class="open-popup-link">
                    <p><strong><%= person.name %></strong></p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <% @occasions.each do |occasion| %>
                <td>
                    <% if @gift.where(person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id) %>  <<<<<<THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE
                        <%= gift.name %>
                    <% else %>
                        <h1>
                            <%= link_to new_gift_path do %>
                                <i class="icon ion-ios-add green"></i>
                            <% end %> <!-- link -->
                        </h1>
                    <% end %> <!-- if/else end -->
                </td>
            <% end %> <!-- occasions each -->
        </tr>
    <% end %> <!-- people each -->
</table>
```

My problem here is that, on the line indicated, I get a `undefined method`where' for nil:NilClass`.  I assume this is because you can't use controller logic like`where` in the view, but I'm not sure how else to phrase this.

Can anyone help me perform this task successfully and in the most "railsy" way?

Comment: can you add your controller code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:

search the result if there is an result then print it, this will prevent an error with nil value

```
  <% gift = Gift.where(person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id) %>
  <% gift != [] %>
      <%= gift.name %>
  <% else %>
      <h1>
          <%= link_to new_gift_path do %>
              <i class="icon ion-ios-add green"></i>
          <% end %> <!-- link -->
      </h1>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: @gift can't be defined in the controller though, as it changes from cell to cell of the table...

Comment: For some reason `any` still threw up an error, but with `if gift != [] ` it works!

Comment: thanks for your info, the return value is an array class and possibly <% if gift %> will also work for your problem.

Comment: `<% if gift %>` didn't actually work because `[]` (aka an empty array) still isn't `nil`...just fyi...

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if @occasions.gifts && @occasions.gifts.where(person_id: person.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this is because you can't use controller logic likewhere` in the view

This is not the problem, first thing `where` is not controller logic, it is model logic, second, it is just called on the model(s), it doesn't matter where, it can be invoked from anywhere in your codebase as long as it is on the model.

in terms of your error, you are getting it because `@gift` instance variable is not set, it is `nil`, are you setting this variable anywhere before you call it?

In the block:

```
<% if @gift.where(person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id) %>  <<<<<<THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE
    <%= gift.name %>
<% else %>
    <h1>
        <%= link_to new_gift_path do %>
            <i class="icon ion-ios-add green"></i>
        <% end %> <!-- link -->
    </h1>
<% end %>
```

Your first problem is that as mentioned above your `@gift` variable is nil, second, you are then calling name on another unset local variable `gift` when you write `<%= gift.name %>`.

I assume you are after something along the lines of

```
<% gift = occasion.gifts.find_by(person_id: person.id) %>
<% if gift.present? %>
    <%= gift.name %>
<% else %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

As you may have noticed I have changed `.where` to `.find_by` as well, this is because '.where' will return a collection, where as looking at your code you are looking to display a single gift record's name.